# JPA result infinite loop when using @OneToMany

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have two entities called Course and Topic. It is a One-to-Many relationship. When I get list of all Courses, I get weird results. It looks like it is getting a long infinite loop results (The JSON response that I got is just part of it but it keeps going and going)

[Picture of my ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLNUR.png)

```
[
    {
        "id": "Java",
        "name": "Java",
        "descr": "This course goes over Java",
        "topic": [
            {
                "id": "java-core",
                "name": "Java core",
                "descr": "This topic goes over java core",
                "course": {
                    "id": "Java",
                    "name": "Java",
                    "descr": "This course goes over Java",
                    "topic": [
                        {
                            "id": "java-core",
                            "name": "Java core",
                            "descr": "This topic goes over java core",
                            "course": {
                                "id": "Java",
                                "name": "Java",
                                "descr": "This course goes over Java",
                                "topic": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "java-core",
                                        "name": "Java core",
                                        "descr": "This topic goes over java core",
                                        "course": {
                                            "id": "Java",
                                            "name": "Java",
                                            "descr": "This course goes over Java",
                                            "topic": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "java-core",
                                                    "name": "Java core",
                                                    "descr": "This topic goes over java core",
                                                    "course": {
                                                        "id": "Java",
                                                        "name": "Java",
                                                        "descr": "This course goes over Java",
                                                        "topic": [
                                                            {
                                                                "id": "java-core",
                                                                "name": "Java core",
                                                                "descr": "This topic goes over java core",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`@JsonManagedReference` annotation for the first objects instantiated

`@JsonBackReference` annotation for the second objects instantiated